# Loop from Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, loops, google-visualization

I'm trying to do a loop from a Google sheet whereby I come out of it with a0, a1, a2 and so on.  I am able to manually setup the variable but I can't get the loop correct.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {
    packages: ['gauge']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(queryValue);

function queryValue() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=B22:B37&key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdFNhSzNQUFd3b1ZfRHgtQURINFpzeGc&gid=7');
    query.send(function (response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }
        var data = response.getDataTable();

        //date label loop
        for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
            document.getElementById('b' + (i + 22)).innerHTML = data.getValue(i, 0);
            console.log("i =" + b22)
        }

    });
    queryValue1()
}

function queryValue1() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=A22:A37&key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdFNhSzNQUFd3b1ZfRHgtQURINFpzeGc&gid=7');
    query.send(function (response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }
        var data1 = response.getDataTable();
        var a1 = data1.getValue(0, 0);
        var a2 = data1.getValue(1, 0);
        var a3 = data1.getValue(2, 0);
        var a4 = data1.getValue(3, 0);
        var a5 = data1.getValue(4, 0);
        var a6 = data1.getValue(5, 0);
        var a7 = data1.getValue(6, 0);
        var a8 = data1.getValue(7, 0);
        var a9 = data1.getValue(8, 0);
        var a10 = data1.getValue(9, 0);
        var a11 = data1.getValue(10, 0);
        var a12 = data1.getValue(11, 0);
        var a13 = data1.getValue(12, 0);
        var a14 = data1.getValue(13, 0);
        var a15 = data1.getValue(14, 0);
        var a16 = data1.getValue(15, 0);

        queryValue3(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12, a13, a14, a15, a16);
    });


}

function queryValue3(met1, met2, met3, met4, met5, met6, met7, met8, met9, met10, met11, met12, met13, met14, met15, met16) {
    var query3 = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=B2:B17&key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdFNhSzNQUFd3b1ZfRHgtQURINFpzeGc&gid=10');
    query3.send(function (response) {
        if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query3: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
        }

        var data3 = response.getDataTable();

        var m1 = data3.getValue(0, 0);
        var m2 = data3.getValue(1, 0);
        var m3 = data3.getValue(2, 0);
        var m4 = data3.getValue(3, 0);
        var m5 = data3.getValue(4, 0);
        var m6 = data3.getValue(5, 0);
        var m7 = data3.getValue(6, 0);
        var m8 = data3.getValue(7, 0);
        var m9 = data3.getValue(8, 0);
        var m10 = data3.getValue(9, 0);
        var m11 = data3.getValue(10, 0);
        var m12 = data3.getValue(11, 0);
        var m13 = data3.getValue(12, 0);
        var m14 = data3.getValue(13, 0);
        var m15 = data3.getValue(14, 0);
        var m16 = data3.getValue(15, 0);

        var red22 = "<span style='color:#ff0000'> ";
        var yellow22 = "<span style='color:#FF9900'> ";
        var green22 = "<span style='color:#009900'> ";
```

This code queries a Google Sheet and draws 16 gauges on a page dynamically changing the month the data was recorded and the labels on the gauges change colors to match the color on the gauge, red, yellow, or green.  [This is the page](http://landash.com/samples/gauges7.html)

As you can see I have some room for improvement.  I've managed to get it all working, but I short a couple of loops.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be far more effective to return an array, rather than a variable.

Something like this:

```
var a = [];
for (var z = 0; z <= 15; z++) {
  a[z] = data1.getValue(z, 0);
}
```

To get the value of a0, a1, a2, etc. you would instead just use a[0], a[1], a[2], etc.

Comment: How would I pass the values onto the next function?  I get an error of unexpected identifier in the queryValue line.

Comment: Okay, let's take a step back. What are you trying to accomplish with the data? What happens to variables A0 to A15 after you've created them? Once we figure that out, we can move on to how best to do that.

Comment: I posted more code and the link to the page.  It all works, but I am missing two loops.  I've tried to get them working to no avail.

Comment: I still can't see what you're trying to do. What are you passing the variables to do? I think there's a fundamental gap between the question you're asking, and the solution you actually want, but without understanding why you're passing values willy-nilly, I can't figure out how to make an easier way for you to use them...